# Unable to select .jsx

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

I use a text editor to edit a .jsx file. I saved it with a .jsx extension. It is not selectable when I try to load it in photoshop. Mac still recognises it as a .txt file although it is saved with a .jsx extension.

This is the first time I work with photoshop script. Have I missed any configurations or do I need a different program to edit .jsx file for photoshop?

Thanks

---

Added screenshots

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do you load it? Is your mac M1?

Comment: HI @SergeyKritskiy Thanks. I saved it in Photoshop's *Scripts* folder and tried to select it via photoshop File > Script > Browse. No, Is not M1. The mac is a 2018 model.

Comment: Generally though, when you put scripts in PS's scripts folder, you can then see the script in `File > Scripts > your script` for convenience... But if you're using `File > Scripts > Browse...` the script can be in any folder. So you're kinda mixing 2 ways to launch the scripts unnecessarily. — As for the actual issue, what if you duplicate one of the existing files in the script folder and just replace the contents and save?

Comment: Thanks @Joonas I think maybe because it is not recognisable as an executable script file, hence it doesn't show up in File < Scripts > *menu* Yes, I've tried to duplicate the original file, edit and save with a .jsx extension. It is still the same. It is not recognized as a .jsx file although in the .jsx extension.

Comment: Sounds like there's an error in the script, not a file naming issue.

Comment: If you can't select the file in the `Browse...` dialog, maybe your Finder has the setting `Show all extensions` disabled and when you make the file `Jpeg100.jsx`, it's actually something like `Jpeg100.jsx.txt`. Although I'm not entirely sure a file can be saved that way from the save dialog. I'd say no, but...? The other thing that comes to mind is maybe there's a misunderstanding about the descriptiong "Unable to select" and what is happening is that the script is corrupted. It could be possible to open a file in TextEdit and save RTF data as a plaintext essentially ruining the script.

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary, but try editing the script with [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) instead.

Comment: Or just change the suffix to `.js` (in the Finder). If the script is written correctly it'll still work. The `x` isn't really mandatory (at least on a Mac). -- realize no one here knows what the script looks like or what you've edited. it's *entirely possible* you "broke" the file while editing.

Comment: @Joonas Yes! You are right! is in ```jsx.txt```.  After changing it to .jsx and it works! Thanks!!!

Comment: Thanks @Scott! I didn't know is not mandatory to have that ```x```. Glad to know it now!

Answer (score 1):

**after question edit and comments**

If the file was placed in the Scripts folder... 
it should appear in the menu. Under `File > Scripts >`

That's how you call scripts which are in the folder. 
You don't really "load" them.

If it doesn't appear there or appears there and does nothing when selected... then the script is written incorrectly or has an error within it.

---

Make certain TextEdit saved the file as **plain text**.

From the menu choose `Format > Make Plain Text`

By default Apple's TextEdit saves as *rich text*, which won't work.

An easy way to tell is if you have the menu across the top of the document window....

[image]

If you see that, or something similar, then the file is *rich text* and the format needs to be changed when writing scripts or markup. There will be no options across the top of a plain text document window.

You can set TextEdit's **Preferences** to create new documents as *plain text* by default.

Just as a sidebar, if you plan on doing a lot of script, code, or markup writing, [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/) is a great app that's much, much, much better than Apple's TextEdit. It has a "free mode" I'd encourage you to check out.

(I'm not affiliated with BBEdit or BareBones software in *any* way. Simply a long time user.)

Comment: Thanks @scott. I've added the screenshots. I think it is already saved in plain text.